# IE7 z-index problem with Flash content

Tags: css, flash, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I have a problem with flash content in IE7 being always over the menu items

I have a structure like the following:

```
<div id='skyscraper_flash'>
<!--this id skyscraper_flash is position absolute-->
  <object>
   <!--this is wmode transparent-->
  </object>
</div>

<div id='menu'>
<!--this id menu is also position absolute-->
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now then the last item of the menu opens it shows behind the flash content. The skyscraper is on the right of the page content. What should i look into?

Comment: Can you post the CSS for us too? You mention z-indexes but haven't told us what they are :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give this inside the object tag

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Comment: It is already initialized as wmode transparent as you can see in the pseudo-code above

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to change the z-index of the menu and add wmode="transparent" like above

Comment: object is initialized with wmode=transparent as i wrote in the pseudo-code. As for z-index, aren't generally position:absolute elements out of z-index logics?

Comment: z.index applies only to positioned elements, so if you haven't declared a z-index to your elements, you won't be able to control which one is on top...

Answer (score 0):

opaque for performance

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
```

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=E5141