# DNN - skin is fine in IE9 and IE8 but breaks in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, dotnetnuke

I am working on a dnn site. The skin looks perfect in firefox, IE9 and IE8 but breaks in IE7. Is there a quick fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably isn't DotNetNuke related.  Flash does that in IE7 if you do not set your wmmode to transparent in your flash object. Here's a related article via Stack Overflow:

[IE7 z-index problem with Flash content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652998/ie7-z-index-problem-with-flash-content)